# mySQl in XAMPP wont start (tried changing ports)

Tags: mysql, xampp

So yesterday everything was working fine, but today when I wanted to continue mySQL wouldnt start. Also my laptop shutdown at night if that is relevant. I have tried changing the port to 3307 but it didnt work.
Anyway here is the log

```
2016-08-19 12:55:09 1b34 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
160819 12:55:09 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
160819 12:55:09 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
160819 12:55:09 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
160819 12:55:09 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
160819 12:55:09 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
160819 12:55:09 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
160819 12:55:09 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
160819 12:55:09 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
160819 12:55:09 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
160819 12:55:09 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 1665234 and 1665234 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 1778208 in the ib_logfiles!
160819 12:55:09 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
160819 12:55:09 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
160819 12:55:09 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
160819 12:55:09 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages 
160819 12:55:09 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
160819 12:55:09 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
160819 12:55:09 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
160819 12:55:09 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.22-72.0 started; log sequence number 1778208
160819 12:55:09 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
160819 12:55:09 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

And this is what it said in when I tried connecting.

```
5:10:04  [mysql]    Attempting to start MySQL app...
15:10:04  [mysql]   Status change detected: running
15:10:04  [mysql]   Status change detected: stopped
15:10:04  [mysql]   Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
15:10:04  [mysql]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
15:10:04  [mysql]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
15:10:04  [mysql]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
15:10:04  [mysql]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
15:10:04  [mysql]   If you need more help, copy and post this
15:10:04  [mysql]   entire log window on the forums
```

Comment: Surely there is more in the log? Probably something about not being able to recover the database correctly and showing you some suggestions on what to do.

Comment: Nope. This is the whole mysql_error.log copy/pasted.